# Application Roles in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

On [this site](http://thesqldude.com/2012/04/07/how-to-prevent-users-from-accessing-sql-server-from-any-application-or-any-login-expect-your-main-application-its-login/) SQLDude talks about Application roles for MSSQL Server.

> A more secure approach you could use for this is called "Application Roles". When connecting from an application you assume a particular role and only that role is granted privileges required in the database. So all apps connect via this mechanism and don’t give out SQL or NT logins for any unauthorised use. You will have to call sp_setapprole in your application with a password, once the connection is established. Once this call succeeds then the connection gets the privileges of the application role and loses privileges of the actual user, which is what we want. So if someone tried to connect to the database from SSMS or SQLCMD, they will access the DB using their credentials, which won’t have the required permissions on the tables, since only the application role has the rights on the tables. This is more secure & reliable approach, but one that requires application code change and as a DBA you will have to create the application role in SQL Server.

However i can't find the equivalent for PostgreSQL? 
Is there something like this available in PostgreSQL?

Comment: A "role"? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html and then use `set role` after connecting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name uh i totally missed that you can set a password for roles in postgresql. please make your comment an answer and i will accept it.